# What's better to use and why?

Tags: c++, refactoring

```
class MyClass {
    private:
        unsigned int currentTimeMS;
    public:
        void update() {
            currentTimeMS = getTimeMS();
            // ...
        }
};

class MyClass {
    public:
        void update() {
            unsigned int currentTimeMS = getTimeMS();
            // ...
        }
};
```

update() calls in main game loop so in the second case we get a lot of allocation operations (unsigned int currentTimeMS). In the first case we get only one allocate and use that allocated variable before.
Which of this code better to use and why?

Comment: It depends. Do you need the `currentTimeMS` variable anywhere else? Somewhere where you can't call `getTimeMS` directly?

Comment: There's not enough code or content in the question to answer this. Also, your title, seriously?

Comment: in the first snippet, is `getTimeMS();` supposed to be `getTimeMS;` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend the second variant because it is stateless and the scope of the variable is smaller. Use the first one only if you really experience a performance issue, which I consider unlikely.

If you do not modify the variable value later, you should also consider to make it `const` in order to express this intent in your code and to give the compiler additional optimization options.

Comment: How can your recommend that?  You don't know what he's doing with the result . It may need to be used elsewhere.

Comment: @afrogonabike: From his code example I conclude that the variable is only used in the `update()` method. Otherwise he would not have both options.

Comment: yes I guess that is true.  What is unknown is whether the OP is lacking basic understanding of class declarations or whether the question goes deeper than that.  OP?

Comment: I agree with your first sentence and maybe with your const, but in c++ (I don't know about java) there is no reason whatsoever to believe the first option would be faster (if there is a difference a t all, I'd expect the contrary)

Comment: There will be no difference in performance. The method's variable will be allocated on the stack, which is a no-op (the stack pointer needs to move anyway, it doesn't matter how much it does. The latter option is definitely better if the variable is only used in `update()`.

Comment: @MikeMB: If the variable has a small scope, I assume it more likely that it will be stored in a lower level cache.

Comment: @HonzaRemeš: There could be a difference (not sure if it matters though): In the first version, `currentTimeMS` has to be a real variable in memory that is accessed indirectly via the `this`-pointer. In the second version, it is a local variable, for which the compiler can perform optimizations much easier. In the extreme case, it might never get commited to memory at all but kept in registers completely.

Comment: @FrankPuffer: Yes, but that reasoning would favor the second, not the first option.

Comment: @MikeMB: Yes, I should amend my comment: "There will be no drop in performance (for the second option) ..."

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your needs. If `currentTimeMS` is needed only **temporarily** in the `update()`, then surely declare it there. (in your case, **#option2**)

**But** if it's value is needed for the instance of the class (i.e. being used in some other method), then you should declare it as a field (in your case, **#option1**).

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are saving the state of this class object. In the second one, you're not, so the currentTime will be lost the instant update() is called.

It is really up to you to decide which one you need.

Answer (score 0):

The first case is defining a member variable the second a local variable. Basic class stuff.  A private member variable is available to any function (method) in that class.  a local variable is only available in the function in which it is declared.

Answer (score 0):

> Which of this code better to use and why?

First and foremost, the cited code is at best a tiny micro-optimization. Don't worry about such things unless you have to.

In fact, this is most likely a disoptimization. Sometimes automatic variables are allocated on the stack. Stack allocation is extremely fast (and even free sometimes). There is no need to worry. Other times, the compiler may place a small automatic variable such the `unsigned int` used here in a register. There's no allocation whatsoever.

Compare that to making the variable a data member of the class, and solely for the purpose of avoiding that allocation. Accessing that variable involves going through the `this` pointer. Pointer dereference has a cost, potentially well beyond that of adding an offset to a pointer. The dereference might result in a cache miss. Even worse, this dereferencing may well be performed every time the variable is referenced.

That said, sometimes it is better to create data members solely for the purpose of avoiding automatic variables in various member functions. Large arrays declared as local automatic variables might well result in stack overflow. Note, however, that making `double big_array[2000][2000]` a data member of `MyClass` will most likely make it impossible to have a variable of type `MyClass` be declared as a local automatic variable in some function.

The standard solution to the problems created by placing large arrays on the stack is to instead allocate them on the heap. This leads to another place where creating a data member to avoid a local variable can be beneficial. While stack allocation is extremely fast, heap allocation (e.g., `new`) is quite slow. A member function that is called repeatedly may benefit by making the automatic variable `std::unique_ptr<double> big_array = std::make_unique<double>(2000*2000)` a data member of `MyClass`.

Note that neither of the above applies to the sample code in the question. Note also that the last concern (making an heap-allocated variable a data member so as to avoid repeated allocations and deallocations) means that the code has to go through the `this` pointer to access that memory. In tight code, I've sometimes been forced to create a local automatic pointer variable such as `double* local_pointer = this->some_pointer_member`  to avoid repeated traversals through `this`.